# Can requirement on topology imply requirement on metric structure?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, differential-topology

I am wondering in how far constraints on the topological structure of a space can result in constraints on possible metric structure on that very same space? Is there perhaps even a general theory on how topological considerations go along with restrictions on possible metric structure?

(I am thus in a sense looking for a sort of converse result to the general insight that a metric induces a topology.)

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe if a topology is uncountable or not can give you some restrictions on possible metrics.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_space

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify further: are there any nice general results on how restricting the amount of allowed topologies on a space fixes or at least constrains the metric structure on that space?

Comment: It's not so clear to me what you are after. For example, if $X$ is a compact topological space, then any metric inducing the topology on $X$ must be bounded. Is that the kind of thing you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, exactly

Comment: Your question is still unclear. A metrizable space may have different metrics defining its topology. Are you looking for a topological property leading to a constraint on all of these possible metrics, or just on one of them? For instance, the topology of the Cantor set can be defined by an ultrametric.

Comment: Thanks --- on all of these possible metrics.